# Google rejecting Facebooks json-ld required tags

Tags: json, facebook, json-ld, structured-data

I am setting up JSON+LD tags on my product pages for Facebooks "Dynamic Ads & Commerce".
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/catalog/reference/

Two tags it states are required:

---

**id**
Required for dynamic ads and commerce.

**availability**
Required for dynamic ads and commerce.

---

I've added these, but it causes Google to reject my json+ld markup.

**Invalid enum value in field 'availability'**

1.
[image]

2.
[image]

How could I please both parties here? If I am adding json+ld markup, it may as well have all required elements to be valid on Google and Facebook (Catalog).

```
[
   {
      "@context":"http:\/\/www.schema.org",
      "@type":"Product",
      "name":"Silentnight Safe Nights Toddler Bedset &#8211; 4.5 Tog",
      "title":"Silentnight Safe Nights Toddler Bedset &#8211; 4.5 Tog",
      "url":"http:\/\/myexampledomain.co.uk\/product\/silentnight-safe-nights-toddler-bedset-4-5-tog\/",
      "link":"http:\/\/myexampledomain.co.uk\/product\/silentnight-safe-nights-toddler-bedset-4-5-tog\/",
      "image":"http:\/\/myexampledomain.co.uk\/app\/uploads\/sites\/3\/2019\/10\/silentnight-safe-nights-toddler-bedset-4.5-tog-pack.jpg",
      "image_link":"http:\/\/myexampledomain.co.uk\/app\/uploads\/sites\/3\/2019\/10\/silentnight-safe-nights-toddler-bedset-4.5-tog-pack.jpg",
      "description":"The Silentnight Toddler Duvet and Pillow set makes a great first bed set for your little one. The cot bed sized set includes a snuggly duvet and a soft pillow that is specially designed for children. The slim profile of the pillow offers your child just the right amount of support they need. It's important that small children don't overheat in bed, so the light and soft duvet comes in a 4.5 tog weight rating. Both the pillow and duvet are made from a smooth polycotton cover offering breathable comfort. The products are filled with anti-allergy hollowfibre that actively defends against the bacteria and dust mites that can cause allergies providing a cleaner, fresher and altogether a safer option for a good night's sleep. Our anti-allergy fibres are approved by the British Allergy Foundation, which means they have the ultimate seal of approval. Our fibres have been scientifically tested and are proven to reduce or remove allergens from the indoor environment.\nSuitable only for children over 12 months. Both the pillow and duvet are fully machine washable, and thanks to the easy care polycotton covers, the products have great recovery and can be washed time and time again.",
      "sku":"506984LS",
      "id":17214,
      "productID":17214,
      "offers":[
         {
            "@type":"Offer",
            "price":"30.99",
            "priceCurrency":"GBP",
            "url":"http:\/\/myexampledomain.co.uk\/product\/silentnight-safe-nights-toddler-bedset-4-5-tog\/",
            "gtin":"5012701506984",
            "gtin8":"5012701506984",
            "condition":"new",
            "availability":"in stock",
            "inventoryLevel":54
         }
      ],
      "brand":"Silentnight"
   }
]
```

Comment: It would helpful if you could add your JSONLD code to your question.  (I have no idea what type you are trying to use.)

Comment: @petey - Good point, added the output to original post.